# Aspherical but not contractible

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be the *topologist's sine curve* (i.e. $\left\lbrace (x,y): y=\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),x\in ]0,1]\right\rbrace\cup \lbrace (0,y): y\in [-1,1]\rbrace$) with an arc joining $(0,0)$ and $(1,\sin(1))$, without intersecting the topologist's sine curve.

On the other hand, let's consider the following definition for an *aspherical space* $X$ : A topological space $X$ is said to be aspherical if given any continuous $f:S^{n}\rightarrow X$, there is an extension $g:D_{n+1}\rightarrow X$ (where $D_{n+1}=\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:||x||\leq 1\rbrace$), for any $n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}$.

Can somebody help me/give reference/tell me how I see that $X$ is aspherical but not contractible ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: After realizing I read the question wrong here is a better hint to show asphericity: First notice that a compact path connected subset of $X$ is either $X$ itself or is homeomorphic to the interval. So if $f$ is a nonsurjective continuous map from a sphere into $X$, it maps into an interval and easily extends to a map from the ball. To see that there is no surjective such $f$, consider the preimages of the extreme points of the sine curve; a careful choice of these will give you a convergent sequence in the sphere whose image has two accumulation points in $X$.